# returning a <class 'type'> using random.choices()

Tags: python, oop, scripting

We're currently coding a small game for school, and to pick which powerup spawns, we're using the **choices()** method to have weighted probabilities and to pick from a list containing class names. The problem I'm facing is that since the **choices()** method returns an array, I can't seem to append my object to a list, here's the code, if you have the time to help us...
Thank you

```
def Choice2():
    Type2 = choices([Healboost, DmgsUp, FireRateBoost, ""],weights=proba_powerups) #[0][1][2] are my class names, [3] is for no powerup
    CreatePowerUps(str(Type2)) # converting to str in order to strip "[]"


def CreatePowerUps(a):
    global Time,powerups
    a = a.strip("[]") # removing the "[]"
    print(f"a : {type(a)}") # prints "a : <class 'str'>"
    if Time > 0:
        if a == Healboost :
            powerups.append(a())
        elif a == FireRateBoost :
            powerups.append(a())
        elif a == DmgsUp :
            powerups.append(a())
        elif a == "":
            pass
        if Time > 1200:
            Time -= 10
        print(powerups) # debugging purpose (list stays empty)
        NFP.after(Time,Choice2)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. I can see a few problems with this code, but it's not clear how to fix it with what you've given so far. See [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: Actually nvm, it seems to be a pretty simple fix. I'll write an answer, but a [mre] would still help.

Comment: Why are you converting `Type2` to `str` here: `CreatePowerUps(str(Type2))`? The comment says: "to strip brackets", but why do you need to strip the brackets though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on Earth are you casting the list to a string? You just need to select the first element.

Here's a simplified example:

```
from random import choices

x, y, z = [0, 1, 2]
powerups = []

def choice2():
    type2 = choices([x, y, z, ""], weights=[1] * 4)
    create_power_ups(type2[0])

def create_power_ups(a):
    if a in (x, y, z):
        powerups.append(a)
    print(powerups)

choice2()
```

Run it a few times and you'll see all the different options: `[]`, `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`.

BTW, UpperCamelCase should be reserved for class names, so I fixed that while I was there.

Comment: wow I'm really surprised I didn't even realize I could just pass Type2[0] as the argument, really shows how much of a beginner I am with coding.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, I really need to work on implementing PEP8 rules in my code.